# how to let user download files from node js server?

Tags: nodejs-server

Guys how to enable users to download stuffs from node js server using it's """****core module*****"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's is core module?

if is express frame，this is a download example code

```
router.get('/down', function(req,res){
  let {fn} = req.query
  fn = decodeURI(fn)
  fs.access(`./static/${fn}`, function(err){
    if(!err){
      res.set({
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Disposition": `attachment;filename=${encodeURI(fn)}`
      })
      fs.createReadStream(`./static/${fn}`).pipe(res)
    }
  })
  
})
```